# What is the name of such boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

An elastic body $D$ vibrates. Dirichlet conditions are set on a part of its boundary $\partial D_u$, and Neumann conditions are set on the rest of the boundary $\partial D_p$.
 Difficulty:  $\partial D_u$ and, correspondingly, $\partial D_p$ change with time (in a known way). That is fixed region is "crawling" over the boundary.

I tried to google with many combinations of "Dirichlet", "boundary conditions", "time-dependent", etc, but always got pretty standard things. I guess I'm missing the right keyword.

What is the name of such boundary conditions?
Are there any traps in solving such a problem, for example, by FEM?
Are there any references?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for [mixed boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_boundary_condition), though perhaps also [Robin boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition) also.

Comment: I understand that these are mixed boundary conditions. My difficulty is to specify that Dirichlet and Neumann parts of the boundary change with time.

Comment: I'm saying the boundary condition type you are looking for is called 'mixed'. You are looking for the time dependent version of 'mixed boundary conditions', so Google 'time dependent mixed boundary conditions'. The [first thing that comes up is probably useful](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_20.pdf).

Comment: In the link you give (and all the other links I could find by such and other similar googlings) boundary conditions are time-dependent in the sense that r.h.s of the boundary condition is a function of time, but the separation of the boundary into Dirichlet and Neumann parts is not changing with time. In the notation of my question $u_{\partial D_u} = u_0(t)$, but $\partial D_u = const$. In my case in addition to this there is also $\partial D_u=\partial D_u(t)$ that makes the problem difficult.